# Creating expression by using object ID in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

In a cursor I am trying create an expression by using the ObjectID.

```
Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in Cursor:
    value=row.OBJECTID


    field=arcpy.ListFields(fc,"","OID")[0].name

    expression=field + "='" +value+"'"
```

I need "expression" to be used later in the same script.
but while running this code it gives an error:

> coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Later the expression to be used in selectbyattribute function

```
point_lyr=arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc,"NEW_SELECTION",exp)
```

It gives an invalid expression error

Comment: Have you tried googling that Python error?

Comment: You need to put `value` into a function that converts it to a string form of the number so `str(value)`.

Answer (score 4):

row.OBJECTID returns an integer, and you cannot concatenate an integer with a text (this is what your error message tells: it's looking for a string but it finds an integer instead). There are several ways to convert you integer into string, an easy one would be

> expression=str(field) + "=" +str(value)

a nice way is to use **format**

> expression="{0}={1}".format(arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName, value)

Comment: later in the script i am trying to use it in selectbyattribute function     SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc,"NEW_SELECTION",exp)                                          where it gives an error of "Invalid expression"                                                                   i just used str(value)

Comment: The solution is two-part: 1) Cast or format the int to string, and 2) Not put quotes around an integer type within an expression. This screams for a [switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) by field.type (to handle numeric, date, and string differently), but an `if` will suffice

Comment: Actually, **both** the field name and field vale need to be cast to string (since field.name is Unicode)

Comment: thanks @Vince I only looked at the first error. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an integer rather than a string.

Try:

```
Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in Cursor:
    value = str(row.OBJECTID)

    field = arcpy.ListFields(fc,"","OID")[0].name

    expression = field + "='" + value +"'"
```

or try:

```
Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in Cursor:
    value = row.OBJECTID

    field = arcpy.ListFields(fc,"","OID")[0].name

    expression = field + "='" + str(value) +"'"
```

Comment: i dont know what is the problem here, it gives an invalid expression error in every method which is suggested here.

Comment: That expression cannot be used within a geoprocessing function. It is merely a text string. Please update the question with the part where you need to use the expression again.

Answer (score 1):

The original question asked what the error meant. Now there isn't a question at all, but if the implied "What is wrong here?" is answered, then there are a litany of issues:

1. Using the "Retired" ArcGIS 10.0 (which should have been explicity named in the question)
2. Using "plain vanilla" Cursors instead of Data Access (DA) cursors (only available at 10.1 and up)
3. Naming a single instance of a Cursor object with an uppercase name
4. Not placing an explicit column list in the cursor constructor
5. Naming an object "field" when it's actually the *name* of a field
6. Assuming that the rowid field is the first (zero index) column when no field list was specified
7. Executing ListFields within the cursor loop
8. Constructing a "string" by using addition with a Unicode object in the first element (which is half of the error message)
9. Failing to use the `string.format()` method to construct a string with many differing types (which is the other half)
10. Placing quotes around a numeric type field in a comparison expression

The question also ought to have specified that the data source was a shapefile (much of these issues would cause a failure with non-shapefile sources).  If we apply all these issues, the code is rendered much the same as the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\temp\someshapefile.shape'

oidName = arcpy.ListFields(fc,"","OID")[0].name

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [oidName]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        expression = "{:s} = {:d}".format(oidName,row[0])
        print "expression = '{:s}'".format(expression)
```

If the old (and slow) pre-DA cursors *must* be used, then it would be:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\temp\someshapefile.shape'

oidName = arcpy.ListFields(fc,"","OID")[0].name

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, [oidName])
for row in cursor:
    expression = "{:s} = {:d}".format(oidName,row.getValue(oidName))
    print "expression = '{:s}'".format(expression)
del cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the quotes worked as object ID is an integer.

expression changed to :

```
exp = "{0}={1}".format(field, value)
```

no need to convert objectID to string.

Comment: The "no need to convert objectID to string" part is incorrect. This is *exactly* what `format` accomplishes.